# Best way to parse incoming byte stream?

Tags: python, parsing

I am wondering what the best way to look for a start and end sequence in a byte stream from a file. The way I have been doing this is:

```
begin_msg = [b'B', b'E', b'G', b'I', b'N', b'_', b'M', b'S', b'G', b'#']
end_msg = [b'#', b'E', b'N', b'D', b'_', b'M', b'S', b'G']

with open(file, 'rb') as _file:

begin_id = [b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'']
end_id = [b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'']

if True:

    byte = _file.read(1)

    capturing = False

    while byte != b'':

        begin_id.append(byte)
        begin_id.pop(0)
        end_id.append(byte)
        end_id.pop(0)

        if begin_id == begin_msg:
            capturing = True

        if end_id == end_msg:
            capturing = False
            break

        byte = _file.read(1)

        if capturing:
            byte_message += byte
```

I am sure there is a better way to do this. What is the cleanest way to look for these beginning and ending identifiers?

Comment: What do you think `If True` is doing?

Comment: When begin_msg is found in the code it begins capturing the following bytes. If it hasn't reached the start sequence, its not storing the bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do sounds like something Python's [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re) regular expressions (aka regex) module can handle. You can use it to parse a byte-string (instead of the usual text-string) if you pass it a byte-string to parse and also define your pattern as a byte-string. Note: The easiest way to do that is to use the `b` string prefix in front of them (not in front of each character, as you're doing in your question).

For testing the code coming up I used a file with this in it (sorry, not very imaginative):

```
BEGIN_MSG#
Douglas was here.
#END_MSG
Other stuff
in here.
BEGIN_MSG#
And so
was Roger.
#END_MSG
```

Then used the module on it with the proper regex `pattern` like so:

```
import re

pattern = rb'BEGIN_MSG#(.+?)#END_MSG'
filename = 'bytestream.txt'

with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
    matches = re.findall(pattern, file.read(), flags=re.DOTALL)
    if not matches:
        print('No matches found')
    else:
        print('Matches:')
        for i, match in enumerate(matches, 1):
            print('#{}: {}'.format(i, match))
```

The output from it looks like this, displaying the list of strings returned from `re.findall()`:

```
Matches:
#1: b'\r\nDouglas was here.\r\n'
#2: b'\r\nAnd so\r\nwas Roger.\r\n'
```